# Streamline Cell locking in VBA for Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have this script that locks all the Cells in a workbook that have data in them at save then password protects them. It works fine, but since the workbook has 39 sheets it can take up to 5 min to save Each time. Does anyone know how I can streamline this to make it faster?

```
` Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)


     'Resume to next line if any error occurs
     On Error Resume Next

    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim Cell As Range



    'Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active workbook.
    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    'loop through all of the Worksheets
    For I = 1 To WS_Count
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I)
             'first of all unprotect the entire sheet and unlock all cells
            .Unprotect Password:="password"
            .Cells.Locked = False
             'Now search for non blank cells and lock them
             'unlock blank cells
            For Each Cell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).UsedRange
                If Cell.Value <> "" Then
                    Cell.Locked = True
                ElseIf Cell.Value = "" Then
                    Cell.Locked = False
                End If
            Next Cell
            'Now protect the entire sheet
            .Protect Password:="password"
        End With
    Next I

    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: It may not be any faster, but you could remove that `If` block and replace it with just `Cell.Locked = Cell.Value <> ""`. As for the speed, consider setting `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`  (toggling them back on before exiting the subroutine.

Comment: Not sure whether union the non-blank cells first then setting the `Cell.Locked` value by one time will be faster or not. And how about set the `UsedRange.Locked` directly?

Comment: If you do use "Application.ScreenUpdating = False and Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual", then make sure that you include error handling to make that they get rest back to their initial state.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating one cell at a time to lock them is a time-consuming task. I haven't investigated whether it's the locking or looping that takes the time, but my suspicion is the looping. Certainly, locking a `Range` is much faster.

If, therefore, your worksheets can define a range using the `SpecialCells` function, then that might be a quicker way to go:

```
ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Locked = True
```

There can be problems with this if there are too many areas defining the range (ie VBA doesn't throw an error but just freezes until you hit 'Break') and you'd need to handle the 'no cells found' error.

I've just made such a call on 39 worksheets with 500 rows by 100 columns and 20% random blank cells, and it takes less than a second.

However, you might find that you can 'lock' each worksheet as and when you're done with it (rather than in one big batch prior to saving), for example in the `Worksheet_Deactivate` event. If you persisted the locked state (which you could do, for example, with Named Ranges or on a hidden sheet), then you'd only need to run your locking routine on any which remained open prior to saving. In the sample code below, I've made those assumptions to give you an idea of how it could work. You'd obviously need to change it based on your own criteria and useage, but hopefully it'll get you going. The code is all in the code behind the `ThisWorkbook` object:

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'----------------------------------------------------------
' Initialises worksheet locked states.
' Note 1: only locks the ones which are not locked.
'----------------------------------------------------------
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim n As Name

    On Error GoTo EH

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In Me.Worksheets
        If Not SavedState(ws) Then SavedState(ws) = True
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Exit Sub

EH:
    Debug.Print Err.Number; Err.Description
End Sub

'----------------------------------------------------------
' Iterates the worksheets to lock any that remain unlocked.
'----------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim n As Name

    On Error GoTo EH

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In Me.Worksheets
        If Not SavedState(ws) Then SavedState(ws) = True
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Exit Sub

EH:
    Debug.Print Err.Number; Err.Description
End Sub

EH:
    Debug.Print Err.Number; Err.Description
End Sub

'----------------------------------------------------------
' Unlocks Sheet1 for user to work on.
' CAUTION: not necessarily what you want,
'          but I've put it in as an example of the syntax
'          to unlock any sheet.
'----------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    'Exit if it's not the target sheet.
    If Not Sh Is Sheet1 Then Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo EH
    Set ws = Sh
    SavedState(ws) = False
    Exit Sub

EH:
    Debug.Print Err.Number; Err.Description
End Sub

'----------------------------------------------------------
' Locks this worksheet now that user is finished with it.
'----------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    On Error GoTo EH
    Set ws = Sh
    SavedState(ws) = True
    Exit Sub

EH:
    Debug.Print Err.Number; Err.Description
End Sub

'----------------------------------------------------------
' Gets the saved state of the IsLocked flag.
' Note 1: retrieves value from "IsLocked" named range.
' Note 2: returns False if there's an error.
'----------------------------------------------------------
Private Property Get SavedState(ws As Worksheet) As Boolean
    Dim n As Name

    On Error GoTo EH
    Set n = ws.Names("IsLocked")
    SavedState = n.RefersTo
    Exit Property

EH:
    SavedState = False
End Property

'----------------------------------------------------------
' Sets the saved state of the IsLocked flag.
' Note 1: sets value of "IsLocked" named range.
' Note 2: creates a new named range if it doesn't exist.
'----------------------------------------------------------
Private Property Let SavedState(ws As Worksheet, RHS As Boolean)
    Dim n As Name

    On Error Resume Next
    Set n = ws.Names("IsLocked")
    On Error GoTo EH

    'Create the name if it doesn't exist.
    If n Is Nothing Then
        Set n = ws.Names.Add(Name:="IsLocked", RefersTo:=True)
    End If

    'Set the locked and protection values.
    If RHS Then
        With ws
            .Unprotect "pw"
            .Cells.Locked = False
            On Error Resume Next 'handles no blank cells error.
            .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Locked = True
            On Error GoTo EH
            .Protect "pw"
        End With
    Else
        With ws
            .Unprotect "pw"
            .Cells.Locked = False
        End With
    End If

    'Set the named range value.
    n.RefersTo = RHS
    Exit Property

EH:
    Debug.Print Err.Number; Err.Description
End Property
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this out it seems like it may be a better way to handle this than how I was originally going about it.